# Hotpatching pandas.DataFrame with extended insert method

Tags: python, pandas

[`pandas.DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html?highlight=insert#pandas.DataFrame.insert) can only handle an `int` for it's `loc` kwarg this is inconvenient for the user with medium to big data. In an attempt to solve this problem temporarily for my development environment I have come up with the following methods. I'm testing out as hot patches but I plan on implementing them in my fork of pandas and submitting a PR to the pandas master;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@property
def label_pos(self):
    "Return a dict with column labels as keys and their positions as values."
    return dict(i[::-1] for i in enumerate(self.columns))

setattr(pd.DataFrame, 'label_pos', label_pos)

def label_insert(self, label, *args, **kwargs):
    "Insert an array-like into a DataFrame before a column with the given label."
    self.insert(int(self.label_pos[label]), *args, **kwargs)

setattr(pd.DataFrame, 'label_insert', label_insert)
```

## Testing

```
ex = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10,5)),columns=list('ABCEF'))
D = pd.Series(np.zeros(10))

ex.label_insert(label='C', column='D', value=D)

ex.label_insert('E', 'D', D, allow_duplicates=True)
```